# Extract Entire(a single string) response Using JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am testing a site using `JMeter`. I am creating a `GET` request for getting an account number by an unique id. Which returns only the account number(in String). How can I get the account number in to a `Reference Name` of `JMeter extractor`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say the response has only the Account Number you are looking for,

Use a Beanshell post processor,

```
 vars.put("ACCOUNTNUMBER", prev.getResponseDataAsString());
```

Then you can use ${ACCOUNTNUMBER} , in your test to get the value.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Regular Expression Extractor](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65150-using-regex-regular-expression-extractor-with-jm).

Add `Regular expression extractor` (under Post Processors) as a child of your request. Provide `Reference Name` of your choice. Provide `Regular expression` as `(.+?)`.

Comment: Then what should be the regular expression?

Comment: try (.*) or (.?+) since only account number is returned.

Comment: i made the service to return a `json`..then i used `regular expression extractor` to get the account number..solved but still searching answer of my question..